# How to preserve a Query String after Login(using Google's `userService`) on app engine using Java?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, query-string

I am developing an application in java on GAE(Google App Engine). I have a JSP where I have used Google's `userService` to handle authentication through the gmail account,this works fine  and users are able to Login using Gmail account.

I have used  `userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI())` to create the Login url.

My requirement is that I append some Query Parameter at the end of base url of my application, and I send that url to the user, this is intended to take the user to a specific page with information pulled in from database based on the Query parameter after login.

However, when a user is not logged in and opens the url(having Query String) then it takes him to the Login Page, and after the Login, it is supposed to go to that specific page but after Login the query String is lost and it simply takes the user to the welcome page, which is not intended for this case.

How can I avoid this ? Is there a work around for this or this is just a limitation on App Engine ?

Comment: If you specify that the pages requires login in the web.xml it will auth the user automatically then send you to the page with your original parameters: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went through the article however, it does not have any example on how to enforce login in web.xml.I am a newbie, a small example on how to specify login constraint in web.xml on app engine would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the whole <security-constraint> section to the web.xml , theres not enough room in the comments to show a full example. Copy the whole <security-constraint> block and update it to what your page is.

Comment: I understand that you can't provide a full example here and I also know we can specify security constraint for the urls but how do I make Login compulsory through this. Suppose I have a `welcome.jsp` page and other is `securepage.jsp` and the later is accessible only if you have the right query string attached to the url which gets lost after login.

Comment: I would put the security constrain on the securepage.jsp. If the Query Parameter is not present do a response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp").

Comment: Thanks @Bruyere. It worked, the security constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query String can are preserved if we apply security constraint for the urls which also takes care of the login needed to access the page or url.

`<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Any Name</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/page or url you want to apply the security</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>`